# Given numerous conflicts when rebasing, why does a PR not produce any?

Tags: git, commit, rebase

Prior to creating a PR, I wanted to ensure that my code was up to date with master, so I attempted to `git rebase master`. This produced the dreaded infinite conflict situation, whereby a conflict would be reported by the rebase, I would resolve it, add it, hit `git rebase --continue` and the cycle would repeat - seemingly forever.

However, when I go to create a PR and I see that it reports no conflicts. I check it's comparison view between my branch and `master` and, sure enough, there's no conflicts.

My understand of rebasing tells me that rebasing should simply move my branch commits to be more recent than the latest commit in `master`. I therefore do not entirely understand why a conflict should occur - unless I perhaps don't know what it is that a commit contains?

Answer (score 2):

#### What you're really asking is about the difference between merge and rebase

> My understand of rebasing tells me that rebasing should simply move my branch commits to be more recent than the latest commit in master.

Well, yes, sort of.  But **commits cannot be moved**, which means it's not simple.  In fact, *nothing* about any existing commit can be changed at all.  This is a very strong guarantee, which gives commits much of their value: if you have commit `a123456...` today, and tomorrow, or ten years from now, or any time in the future, you find commit `a123456...` again, you can be sure that it is *exactly the same then* as it is now.

> I therefore do not entirely understand why a [rebase] conflict should occur [if a pull request one does not]

A *pull request* is not exactly a Git thing.  More precisely, Git has `git request-pull`, but this merely builds something suitable for emailing patches.  The kind of pull request you are talking about is something that web sites like GitHub and Bitbucket have added atop Git, and they are built by the web site itself running `git merge`.

On the other hand, running `git rebase` asks *your own* Git to repeatedly invoke `git cherry-pick`, once for each commit to be rebased.  You can see this in action by using `git rebase -i` rather than straight `git rebase`.  There are some oddball corner cases here—sometimes Git does not literally run `git cherry-pick`, and sometimes it does—but this is the fundamental principle.

#### Let's cover that one again because it's really important

A **pull request** on a hosting site, let's call it S for Site, means: *Hey, S: run a `git merge` for me, and see if there are conflicts, and if not, ask someone else to repeat the `git merge`.*

A **`git rebase`** that you run yourself means: *Hey, my own Git: repeatedly cherry-pick certain commits, so as to copy them to new-and-improved commits.*

#### How to understand merge as a verb

The `git merge` command potentially does a lot of things, but the one we care about here is *merge as a verb*, or *to merge*.  This merging action, this *to merge* in Git, is about *combining changes*.  That is, you have some series of commits—I'll draw four of them—on your branch that link to each other, with the last one being the one that your branch name identifies:

```
             o--o--o--L   <-- your-branch
            /
...--o--o--*   (you started with this)
```

Each round `o` here represents a commit.  One of them is starred `*` as it's especially important.  For another one—the *tip* commit of your branch—I used the letter `L` so that I can refer back to it.  `L` stands for Left or Local or `--ours`.

Meanwhile, *someone else* started from the same commit `*` and made some commits:

```
             o--o--o--L   <-- your-branch
            /
...--o--o--*   (you *both* started with this)
            \
             o--o--R   <-- their-branch
```

They have some series of commits that also link (backwards, the way Git does) to the same starting commit `*`.  The tip of *their* branch, I'm calling `R`.  `R` stands for Right or Remote or `--theirs`.

At this point, if you yourself run `git merge their-branch`, or if you get web site S to do the equivalent, your Git (or their Git) *finds* commit `*` automatically for you.  It then does the logical equivalent of this:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-L>   # find out what YOU changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-R>   # find out what THEY changed
```

and proceeds to at least *try* to combine those changes, as viewed from the snapshot in commit `*`.  If you changed something—some set of lines in some file(s)—and they did not, Git takes *your* changes.  If they changed something and you did not, Git takes *their* changes.  If you both made exactly the same change to the same lines of the same file, Git takes *one copy* of those changes.  If you made different changes to the same lines of the same file, Git declares a *merge conflict* and the merge fails.  (With regular `git merge`, you get to clean up the mess yourself.  With an automatic merge on a pull request, web site S does its own cleanup.)

If there are no conflicts, the merge succeeds: Git takes the combined changes, applies them to the contents in commit `*`, and makes a new *merge commit* with two parents:

```
             o--o--o--L
            /          \
...--o--o--*            M
            \          /
             o--o-----R
```

If you're running this `git merge` yourself, commit `M` becomes the new tip of your own branch.  If the web site is doing it, commit `M` is hidden away on the web site (under a special name, `refs/pull/number/merge` for instance).

#### How to understand a rebase via cherry-pick

What `git cherry-pick` does is to *copy* commits, one at a time.  To do so, Git must turn the *snapshot* into a *set of changes*.  To do *that* Git needs to diff the commit against its parent.  Let's start with the same sequence as before, but draw it a bit differently:

```
             I--J--K--L   <-- your-branch
            /
...--o--o--H--P--Q--R   <-- their-branch
```

What you want to end up with is this:

```
             I--J--K--L   [abandoned]
            /
...--o--o--H--P--Q--R   <-- their-branch
                     \
                      I'-J'-K'-L'  <-- your-branch
```

where `I'` is a *copy* of your original `I`, but with some things being different:

- it links backwards not to commit `H`, but to commit `R`, and
- it starts from the snapshot *in* `R`, rather than the snapshot in `H`.

The same goes for `J'` and so on through `L'`: they all must make the same *changes* that `I`, `J`, `K`, and `L` made, but they must make them to the same starting base in `R` as it gets modified in `I'` and `J'` and `K'`.

To achieve this, Git starts by checking out commit `R` on a temporary branch.  Then Git, in effect, converts commit `I`—your first commit to be copied—to a set of changes, by comparing its content to the content in commit `H`.  Git must now *combine* these changes with the changes from `H` to `R`.

This combining uses the same merge machinery we saw with `git merge`, but instead of looking directly `H` vs `L`, we're looking at `H` vs `I` now.  If anything you did in `I` conflicts with anything *they* did in `H`-vs-`R`, you get a conflict, *even if you're going to fix that later in `L`*.

If all goes well—if there are no conflicts—Git makes the copy of `I` as the new ordinary (non-merge) commit `I'`:

```
             I--J--K--L   <-- your-branch
            /
...--o--o--H--P--Q--R   <-- their-branch
                     \
                      I'  <-- HEAD (temporary branch)
```

and goes on to cherry-pick `J`.  To cherry-pick `J`, Git once again uses the *to merge* verb, but this time commit `I` is the "base", so that what you did is whatever you changed in `I`-vs-`J`.  Commit `I'` is the right hand side commit.

If there are merge conflicts, you must resolve them yourself.  If not, or after you have finished, Git makes commit `J'`:

```
             I--J--K--L   <-- your-branch
            /
...--o--o--H--P--Q--R   <-- their-branch
                     \
                      I'-J'  <-- HEAD (temporary branch)
```

This now repeats for `K` and `L`.  So if there are four commits to copy, there are four *to merge* actions that happen, with four opportunities for merge conflicts, *even if you've already carefully fixed them all in the last commit*.

#### Summary

The key difference between this kind of `git merge` and `git rebase` is that the merge starts with one *merge base* commit—the common starting point—and the two *tip commits* to be merged, and combines those changes once, but `git rebase` lists out *every* commit from the common starting point to your own branch tip, then tries to copy them, one at a time, with each copy being a cherry-pick, which is really a merge—so you get one merge *per copied commit*.  That gives you lots of opportunities for conflicts, even if you've already arranged to have them all fixed at the last minute.